# How to publish only specific events from s3 into sqs for files that creating in dynamic folders

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I wonder if there is a way of publishing only filenames with specific rules into SQS from S3.

For example: publish only files that starts with "P" and not last with ".crc"

If it can be solved, does it can only with s3-sqs or I must use also SNS?

can you help?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering?

Comment: yes but i have dynamic folders and i need to adjust it to filter files in dynamic folders

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a bucket level 'Event Notification' [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering), and attach a (first) lambda directly to those events.

The first lambda can do the filtering as you need based on file names, and sends the event further to sqs/sns or a second lambda based on your needs.